# How to automatically delete some text from file names in download dialog window using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Many sites add their domain prefix to file names of downloads. Need to delete it automatically.

```
Example.com_music.mp3
```

It is just internet sites. Of course no access to their servers.
Links don't contain file names. For example:

```
site.com/?file=hgc56gjyd
```

The best solution will be if to make replace in this http header:

```
Content-Disposition    attachment; filename=Example.com_music.mp3
```

How to do this?

Comment: Not sure that you can do that. Only in process of downloading, when you download file on your location then try to rename it.

Comment: The point is in using javascript. Any chance to do that automatically? Maybe after finishing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with usual JavaScript. But it is possible with extension api:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(a) {
    for (var i of a.responseHeaders) {
        if (i.name.match(/Content-Disposition/i)) {
            i.value = i.value.replace("Example.com_", "");
            break;
        }
    }
    return { responseHeaders: a.responseHeaders }
},
{ urls: ["*://site.com/*"] }, ["blocking", "responseHeaders"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for your question, please check this plug in:
http://danml.com/download.html

Comment: I don't see how to make just replace (to delete some text) in that script. It seems to require a certain file name. But it is always different and new and comes from servers in my case.

Comment: You should read download url and extract file name from that an use it in this library

Comment: OK. But how to get a file name from some url if it is not in that url?
http://example.com/?file=hgc56gjyd

Comment: hmm in that case you need to inform your self about page web scraping or javascript web scraping here is tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhdvQQ54jD8  but please search more about javascript and url scraping. That are the basic thing and nobody would create that for you.

Comment: No that is need. It is not similar to scraping (there is no file names in the page code). The only way to get a file name is http request for that url. What is the shortest way to get it using http request?

Comment: It is in Content-Disposition header. How to change it quickly?